# Right position of "including" in academic writing

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, sentence-structure, commas, academic-writing

I saw this in the New York Times,  I am curious to know if the position of "including" is right, especially for academic writing case?

What is the rule of thumb for position of phrases such as "including",  "such as",  "particularly" etc.,  in academic writing?  can we separate them from the phrases they are linked with?

The original sentence in New York Times is:

> "India said it would send humanitarian assistance to Ukraine,
> including medicine, in response to a request from Kyiv"

Is the following sentence more correct than the original one?

> "India said it would send humanitarian assistance, including medicine,
> to Ukraine in response to a request from Kyiv"

Comment: I like the second version more, but both are correct.

Comment: The second is neater prose. Better writing is not necessarily more correct, just clearer and more easily digested.

Comment: Please do a search for "misplaced modifier". You should be able to find advice about where modifiers go in relation to their referents (e.g., when they should be adjacent and when they may be separated).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I second this! There are informative sites on where to appropriately place “interrupters” within a sentence. The second sentence has a much cleaner and clearer placement.

Comment: I think if there were a longer list instead of a single item, it would be better to delay the list.